# Find the particular solution to the following differential equation

Tags: calculus

> Find the particular solution to the following differential equation,
>   $$y′ + 7y  =  x,$$ 
>   satisfying the initial condition  $y(0) = 1$.

The solution that I got was

$$\frac{x}{7}-\frac{1}{49}+\frac{50}{49*e^{6x}}$$

How is this incorrect? What is the correct solution?

Comment: Basically correct, it should be $e^{7 x}$ in the denominator - likely a typo. Also, you can always test your result and make sure the LHS = RHS and that the IC matches to verify results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating factors will be fruitful here, since the RHS is a function of $x$ alone. Multiplying by
$$
\exp(\int7dx)=e^{7x}
$$
we have 
$$
y'e^{7x}+7e^{7x}y=xe^{7x}\implies (ye^{7x})'=xe^{7x}
$$
Can you finish from here?